# Install new software dialog does not show text

Tags: eclipse, installation

If you go to *Help >> Install Newe Software*, a Dialoge open, but the Datawindow, where the list of the available Software have to appear leave empty.

If you click on "Select all" Button, the Message shows, that something is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Solution is:**

Go to */.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/* and rename the file *dialog_settings.xml*.
Switch the Workspace to another (or new one), and switch Back to those one, where you renamed the file.

Now it should work!

Background-Information about [Equinox and P2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started)